# Command for No new row in the table for the existing column

Tags: sql, plsql

Suppose I have a table with 4 column headers a,b,c,d.
In the 1st insert statement, I insert a=1.
So my table T1 contains

```
T1
A B C D
1
```

In 2nd insert statement, I want to insert values like a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4.
So I want the output as

```
T1
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

instead of

```
A B C D
1
1 2 3 4.
```

Point to be noted: The column might not be A all the time. It can be any one of A, B, C, D. i.e; every time I have to check for all the 4 columns if their corresponding values are there or not.

I tried the following code

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B (
    A IN VARCHAR,
    B IN VARCHAR,
    C IN VARCHAR,
    D IN VARCHAR
)

IS 
BEGIN
MERGE INTO MISIMD_FOM_SPM_B2B USING (select 1 from dual) m ON (A=A or B=B or C=C or D=D)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
            A = nv12(A,A,A),
            B = nv12(B,B,B),
            C = nv12(C,C,C),
            D = nv12(D,D,D)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
            A,B,C,D
        ) VALUES (
        A,B,C,D
        );
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
    END INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B;
```

It is giving me the error
PL/SQL statement is ignored and 
missing right parenthesis.

Comment: What went wrong with your existing code? You tried it, but you do not tell us what happened.

Comment: It is giving me the error PL/SQL statement is ignored and missing right parenthesis.

Comment: add the error message as comment here, I can edit the question for you since you probably can't

Comment: I have edited my answer to add some detail questions that are too long to be asked here, as a comment, in a readable way.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your procedure:

- commas missing in the SET clause
- mixup of column and parameter names

Fixing those problems, to at least make it compile, results in:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B (
    pA IN VARCHAR,
    pB IN VARCHAR,
    pC IN VARCHAR,
    pD IN VARCHAR
) IS 
BEGIN
MERGE INTO MISIMD_FOM_SPM_B2B USING (select 1 from dual) m ON (A=pA or B=pB or C=pC or D=pD)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
            A = nvl(A,pA),
            B = nvl(B,pB),
            C = nvl(C,pC),
            D = nvl(D,pD)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
            A,B,C,D
        ) VALUES (
            pA,pB,pC,pD
        );
END INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B;
/
```

But that still does not work, as it throws an exception during execution:

```
exec INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(1,null,null,null)

ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"
ORA-06512: at "MYSCHEMA.INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
*Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause
```

Not sure if MERGE can somehow be convinced to do what you want it to do, but you can use this procedure instead, making use of the `sql%rowcount` result counter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B (
    pA IN VARCHAR,
    pB IN VARCHAR,
    pC IN VARCHAR,
    pD IN VARCHAR
) IS 
BEGIN
  update MISIMD_FOM_SPM_B2B
    set A = nvl(A,pA),
        B = nvl(B,pB),
        C = nvl(C,pC),
        D = nvl(D,pD)
    where A = pA
       or B = pB
       or C = pC
       or D = pD;
  if sql%rowcount=0 then
    insert into MISIMD_FOM_SPM_B2B (A, B, C, D)
      values ( pA, pB, pC, pD );
  end if;
END INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B;
/
```

You should be aware that this kind of merging is awfully slow...

BTW, what is desired outcome for this sequence of procedure calls:

```
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(1,null,null,null);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(null,2,null,null);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(null,null,3,null);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(null,null,null,4);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(1,2,3,4);
```

Or this one:

```
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(1,null,null,1);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(null,2,null,2);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(1,2,null,null);
```

Comment: I have added a on both the sides to make it easy. But my actual code was different and thanks for pointing it out and for the solution.

Comment: In the case of 1st calls to the procedure, it should be 
A B C D
1 2 3 4
In 2nd case, it will give the error because as 1 value of any variable contains only 1 value of other variables. Like for a=1 b can be only 2 and c can be only 3 and d can be only 4 and vice versa

Comment: What is the desired result after executing only `INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(1,null,null,null);
INSERT_FOM_SPM_B2B(null,2,null,null);`, should those already be merged to `1,2,null,null` or not yet?

Comment: yeah, they should be merged or as they are already existing you don't need to modify it. But the output needs to be (1, 2, null, null)

Answer (score 0):

This version worked.But you should pay attention about naming standards.

```
create or replace procedure insert_fom_spm_b2b (param_a   in varchar,
                                                param_b   in varchar,
                                                param_c   in varchar,
                                                param_d   in varchar)
is
begin
   merge into misimd_fom_spm_b2b x
        using (select param_a param_a,
                      param_b param_b,
                      param_c param_c,
                      param_d param_d
                 from DUAL) m
           on (   (m.param_a, 'dummy') = ( (x.a, 'dummy'))
               or (m.param_b, 'dummy') = ( (x.b, 'dummy'))
               or (m.param_c, 'dummy') = ( (x.c, 'dummy'))
               or (m.param_d, 'dummy') = ( (x.d, 'dummy')))
   when matched
   then
      update set
       a= NVL (param_a, a),  b = NVL (param_b, b), c = NVL (param_c, c), d = NVL (param_d, d)
   when not matched
   then
      insert     (a,
                  b,
                  c,
                  d)
          values (param_a,
                  param_b,
                  param_c,
                  param_d);
exception
   when others
   then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
end insert_fom_spm_b2b;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have deliberately provided them as a,b,c,d for easy processing. Thanks for pointing out and for the solution. But in the solution, you are only adding the check for 'a' and like I already mentioned it might be with any column. In that case do i need to add more if loops?

Comment: for that there is a different solutions .I'm editing script.